# Testing service which depends on ContainerRef

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner, stub, angular-test

I'm trying to make tests for a service that should get `ContainerRef` before any work and following methods insert or remove dynamic components into this container.

I cannot test any of my methods because they require `ContainerRef` to be set.

> this.containerRef.clear is not a function

However, I don't understand how to mock or stub this `ContainerRef`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with

```
service = TestBed.get(Service);

service.containerRef = {
    clear(): void {
    },
    insert(viewRef: ViewRef, index?: number): void {
    },
    detach(index?: number): void {
    }
} as ViewContainerRef;

spyOn(service.containerRef, 'clear');
spyOn(service.containerRef, 'insert');
spyOn(service.containerRef, 'detach');
```